# Show body background through element

Tags: css

I have currently set my page background to a tileable image and my header to the same image. To get the two to line up I set `background-position-x` to a value that worked. This is all good until you view it in a different size window. Now they are no longer lined up.

Is there a way to basically make my header, transparent. I know you can set it to `rgba(0,0,0,0)` which is, transparent however it shows white instead of the background image that is set on the body.

Can I do this or is there an easier way to position the header background to line up with the body background regardless of screen size.

A dirty mock-up can be found here: http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/L7jjU/
To actually notice a difference, expand the result window or view in fullscreen here http://jsfiddle.net/spedwards/L7jjU/embedded/result,css,html/

Comment: Not being able to look at your code, couldn't you set the background on the `body` element?

Comment: Maybe have a look at using the opacity property as well?

Comment: @SomeKittensUx2666 Included in my question, I have said that I have the same background set on the body AND the header.

Comment: @Mike `background-color:rgba(0,0,0,0)` does the same as `background-color:rgb(0,0,0);opacity:0`

Comment: Hey Sped, maybe make a fiddle for us so we can see what you are dealing with?

Comment: I'm on my wait out right now. Give me 30 mins or so and I will add one to the question.

Comment: @Mike Sorry for the extra delay. Added an dirty example. If you removed the background on the header, it just shows white. Even if you make it transparent.

Comment: its because you've given your `#pagewrapper` a `background-color:#ffffff;` and as the heading is in the same `div` the background is not setting to transparent